# Section is on page after title with an empty page

Tags: sectioning, pdfpages

I am inserting a PDF into my document and the issue is that the section title is at the top of a page and the rest of that page is entirely empty but and the PDF starts on the next page. At first I figured it was an issue with size because the default size filled the whole page so I kept changing the scale of the PDF but even with it at a quarter of the size and taking up very little space it still won't go on the same page as my section title. Any ideas? Below is what I am using to start my section and insert the PDF.

```
\section{Router IP Address}
\label{sec:router}

\begin{center}
\includepdf[pages=-]{router_ip.pdf}
\end{center}
```

Comment: if you use `\includepdf` then that is always a complete page. If you want to include a pdf into part of a page, use `\includegraphics`

Comment: Thanks, everywhere online says to use `\includepdf` if you have multipage documents so that is what I went with.

Comment: That means if you want to insert 3 consectuive pages you can do that with includepdf but you can't with includegraphics, but you can do `\includegraphics[page=7]{zzz.pdf}` to include page 7 of a pdf into a single  region in your document

Comment: Right, so to include multiple pages I just do a bunch of `\includegraphics[page=n]{pdfname.pdf}` in a row? At least that seems to work for me.

Comment: yes, pdfpages simplifies it if they are complet pages but otherwise that's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `\includepdf` then that is always a complete page. If you want to include a pdf into part of a page, use `\includegraphics`, perhaps with a `page=...` option to select a single page out of the PDF.